# Mongodb query (hashmap objects)

Tags: mongodb

I want to query all the UserGroup's ID where admins's ID="25160228446835585906563830293" or users's ID ="25160228446835585906563830293".

this is a hashmap key and value pair in java obj `hashmap<String,Date>`
`"25160228446835585906563830293" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z")`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51512958849ca4748271c640"), 
  "_class" : "com.pcd.app.model.UserGroup", 
  "groupName" : "sdfsadfsad", 
  "privacyType" : "PRIVACY_OPEN", 
  "approvalType" : "MEMBER_APPROVAL", 
  "groupDescription" : "test", 
  "admins" : { 
      "25160228446835585906563830293" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z"),
      "25160228446835585906563830294" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z"),
      "25160228446835585906563830295" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") 
  },
  "users" : { 
      "25160228446835585906563830296" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried? Fyi: It will need to scan through all documents if the keys aren't fixed and indexed.

Comment: I am totally new to mongodb or any NoSql db, so can I index the middle of "string"? in java obj, i know it is a key but how does the mongodb knows that is a key?

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you restructure your document to make it indexable and more easily searched in MongoDB.

Instead of using the `id` of the `admin` as a field, add each `admin` as an object of an array:

```
    "admins" : [
        { id: "25160228446835585906563830293",
           date: ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") }
     ],
```

This will make searches more natural:

```
db.so.find( { "admins.id" : 
    { $in: ['25160228446835585906563830293', 
            '25160228446835585906563830296']}})
```

You can use the `$in` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in)) operator to look for `admin`s with an `id` that matches the list as you wanted (`admins.id`).

So, given a Java `QueryBuilder`, it might look something like this:

```
BasicDBList adminIds = new BasicDBList();
adminIds.addAll(ids); // the ids could be a List<String> 
DBObject inClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", adminIds);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("admins.id", inClause);
```

You may want to use `ensureIndex` to build an index ([docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#ensureIndex%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29)).

Based on your original example, here's the full document for reference:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("51512958849ca4748271c640"), 
    "_class" : "com.pcd.app.model.UserGroup", 
    "groupName" : "sdfsadfsad", 
    "privacyType" : "PRIVACY_OPEN", 
    "approvalType" : "MEMBER_APPROVAL", 
    "groupDescription" : "test", 
    "admins" : [
        { id: "25160228446835585906563830293" ,
          date: ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") },
        { id: "25160228446835585906563830294" , 
          date:  ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") },
        { id: "25160228446835585906563830295" , 
          date: ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") } 
    ],
    "users" : [
        { id: "25160228446835585906563830296", 
          date : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I will have to look into it how to make my own custom converter for the spring data.

Comment: What if I want to upsert into the admin field? For example, I want to edit the date or add a new admin field with the date if the admin doesn't already exist?

Comment: @Ryan_DS-please ask a new question. This answer is nearly 7 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongodb java driver you can do the following:

```
   BasicDBObject queryForAdminsID = new BasicDBObject("admins." + adminsID, new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));  
// BasicDBObject queryForUsersID = new BasicDBObject("users." + usersID, new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
cursor = coll.find(query); // coll is a DBCollection

try {
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
} finally {
 cursor.close();
}
```

where `usersID` and `adminsID` are your ids

Comment: Ok but what about I want to query, 25160228446835585906563830293 from the one column?

"admins" : { 
      "25160228446835585906563830293" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z"),
      "25160228446835585906563830294" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z"),
      "25160228446835585906563830295" : ISODate("2013-03-26T04:51:36.731Z") 
  }

Comment: then you should define adminsID as following and pass to the code above. It will return you whole data back. String adminsID = "25160228446835585906563830293"

Comment: Ok thanks, will try that, so is that possible to use one query instead of two? for admins and users in one query?

Comment: I did only single queries before, but you can try to add them into a single BasicDBObject and then try to query it.. But then it will be an AND query, not OR